# Unable to send the cookie with cookieName

Tags: magento2

when i execute this code after purchase with 3 products or more

```
$cartManagement = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface::class);
                    $orderId = $cartManagement->placeOrder($quote->getId());
```

or

```
$orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($quote->getId());
```

I get this error:  *Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException: Unable to send the cookie with cookieName = X-Magento-Vary*

Increase the values in PhpCookieManager.php but the same error continues

const MAX_NUM_COOKIES = 500;
const MAX_COOKIE_SIZE = 40960;
const EXPIRE_NOW_TIME = 1;
const EXPIRE_AT_END_OF_SESSION_TIME = 0;

what is the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. All you have to do now is clean cache and check in the incognito mode. Also, disable varnish if not done.

You can refer here: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/84

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I have tried in the browsers of Edge, Chrome, Firefox incognito mode also clear cache, cookies but the same problem continues :(